# Plot fractional trigonometric functions with the Mittag-Leffler function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

[image]

Can anyone help please? 
Im trying to plot the solution $X$ of the system as in the paper attached - about fractional calculus which is 
$X= [E_{\nu}(2t^{\nu})][2 \cos_{\nu}(3t^{\nu})+4 \sin_{\nu}(3t^{\nu})]$
where $E$ is the Mittag-Leffler function 
and the defintions of $\cos_{\nu}$ and $\sin_{\nu}$ are in the paper also.

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is the commands in mathematica to get the graphs of the solution $ x = [ mittageleffler (2t^v)] [ 2cos _v(3t^v)+4Sin _v(3t^ )] as in the photo  ; Thanks

Comment: Maybe the downvoters can chill a bit, working with the Mittag-Leffler function is not easy, and Jojo is a beginner.

Comment: For future reference, I think it is best to add an opening paragraph before embedding images. I had to scroll through carefully to see that it was not an image-only post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm understanding the notation right, but think that you can express all of these functions in terms of the builtin [`MittagLefflerE`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MittagLefflerE.html).

For the fractional cosine and sine definitions I'm using $z=x^{\alpha}$:

```
fcos[α_, z_] = Sum[(-z^2)^k/Gamma[1+2*α*k], {k, 0, ∞}]
```

> MittagLefflerE[2 α, -z^2]

```
fsin[α_, z_] = Sum[(z*(-z^2)^k)/Gamma[(1+α)+2*k*α], {k, 0, ∞}]
```

> z MittagLefflerE[2 α, 1 + α, -z^2]

For the fractional exponential I'm using $z=i x^{\alpha}$:

```
fexp[α_, z_] = fcos[α, z/I] + I*fsin[α, z/I]
```

> MittagLefflerE[2 α, z^2] + z MittagLefflerE[2 α, 1 + α, z^2]

With these we can define your $X$-function:

```
X[ν_, t_] = fexp[ν, 2*t^ν]*(2*fcos[ν, 3*t^ν] + 4*fsin[ν, 3*t^ν])
```

> (2 MittagLefflerE[2 ν, -9 t^(2 ν)] + 12 t^ν MittagLefflerE[2 ν, 1 + ν, -9 t^(2 ν)]) (MittagLefflerE[2 ν, 4 t^(2 ν)] + 2 t^ν MittagLefflerE[2 ν, 1 + ν, 4 t^(2 ν)])

Plot for $\nu=1$: using `Evaluate` to speed up the plotting dramatically,

```
Plot[Evaluate@X[1, t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Plot for $\nu=0.8$: much slower as we cannot use the `Evaluate` trick,

[image]

I cannot read the labels on your other plots and so cannot reproduce them. What are their parameters $\nu$ and their axis labels?